# Get windows version in Cygwin

Tags: windows, bash, scripting, cygwin

How can I get the windows version I am currently running under Cygwin?

I am maintaining a automatic build script that is running on Mac, Windows and Linux distributions and I need to be able to detect what Windows version it is currently running under.

Preferably I could have it return the standard Windows release name but some kind of code that I can separate from the other ones would also be great.

What I want to know is if I am running 7, XP, Server 2008 and so on.

Help, Ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this:

```
eh@winxpsp3 ~
$ echo `cmd /c ver`
 Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]

eh@winxpsp3 ~
$
```

Comment: Perfect, even though on Win7 that did not give the "Mirosoft Windows 7" but atleast the code is there and version 6 of Windows is all Win7 I believe.

Thanks

Comment: This only works in certain cases, as your comment shows. I know that I'm running Windows8, Version 6.2.9200 under my Cygwin. This answer simply returns: `Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200]` @Sedrik, note that this shows that _not_ all Windows with Version 6 is Windows 7. Another quick note: I think backticks are deprecated; one should use `$ echo $(cmd /c ver)`. (For me `$ cmd /c ver` gave the same output, minus a leading space.) See the answer @Costa gave for some more info (including something that reads "Windows 8" for me.).

Comment: @bballdave025:
Here are reason for extra space. `cmd` output has windows line-ends, `ver` outputs empty line before os version itself. Shell backticks trims spaces, tabs (`\t`) and newlines (`\n`) around output, but not carriage-returns (`\r`). Newlines inside output backticks converts to spaces (unless backtick used in double-quotes). As a result newline between carriage-returns and version converted by backticks to space.

Answer (score 10):

You can grep it out of the Windows `systeminfo` utility.

```
systeminfo | grep '^OS'
```

OS name only:

```
systeminfo | sed -n 's/^OS Name:[[:blank:]]*//p'
```

Example:

```
$ systeminfo.exe | grep '^OS'
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 7 Home Premium
OS Version:                6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601
OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
OS Configuration:          Standalone Workstation
OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
$ systeminfo | sed -n 's/^OS Name:[[:blank:]]*//p'
Microsoft Windows 7 Home Premium
```

Comment: This should be the chosen answer. The accepted answer (for me) simply returns: `Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200]`, while this answer returns everything: `OS Name: Microsoft Windows 8   \OS Version: 6.2.9200 N/A Build 9200   \OS Manufacturer: Microsoft Corporation   \OS Configuration: Standalone Workstation   \OS Build Type: Multiprocessor Free`. If I use the `sed` stuff, I get exactly that for which the OP was asking.

Answer (score 8):

You could use `uname -s` and compare the output to this:

> NT-5.0 = W2000
>
> NT-5.1 = XP
>
> NT-6.0 = Vista
>
> NT-6.1 = W7

I'm running Windows 7 64 bit, so my output is:
`CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW64`. You can see more information [here](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2011-03/msg00011.html).

Comment: +1 for a portable answer, since OP uses multiple environments.